# Backreferencing a cookie value in rewriterule

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm trying to backreference a cookie's value in a `RewriteRule` :

```
# Trace rewrite rules log
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace4

# Rewriting the URL, in  the cookie's condition i've tried en alone, and en|fl|nl without sucess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !redirect-lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=(fr|en|nl)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect-lang/%1$1 [R=301,L]
# Test if cookie exist then create it if not
SetEnvIf Cookie "lang=(.*)"  HAVE_locale=
Header set Set-Cookie "lang=fr; path=/;" env=!HAVE_locale
```

The result expected is : `http://example.com/redirect-lang/nl/my/original/url` but I keep having `http://example.com/redirect-lang//my/original/url` (The language code stored in the cookie isn't retrieved.backreference I made isn't correct.

**Edit:** I deleted the cookies and send a request to `http://example.com/testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite` and here is the ouput of the error log:

```
    [....] init rewrite engine with requested uri /testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite
    [....] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite'
    [....] pass through /testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite
    [....] init rewrite engine with requested uri /sites/all/themes/theme_name/img/burger.png, referer: http://front.example.com/testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite
    [....] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/sites/all/themes/theme_name/img/burger.png', referer: http://front.example.com/testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite
    [....] pass through /sites/all/themes/theme_name/img/burger.png, referer: http://front.example.com/testing/redirections/with/apache/mod/rewrite
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please turn on rewrite logging to see what actually happens, and then include the relevant log lines in your question. (Apart from that, it's a good and well-written question and for once I don't think our standard mod_rewrite canonical question answers it.)

Comment: The logs (error log) doesn't return any issue.  And thank you @JennyD for your comment. That is surely encouraging for a beginner (like me ^^)

Comment: You need to turn on some extra logging. Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog for info on how to turn it on; you need both `RewriteLog` and to set `RewriteLogLevel` to at least 3.

Comment: thank you so much for the tip. I've been debugging today and I see better the problem. I'll update the question as soon as I can put it in (understandable) words.

Comment: I edited the question to add the logs.